# Nib view in Xcode Interface builder does not apply autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a Nib view that my coworker has created with working autolayout constraints. When he resizes the view in interface builder the constraints are applied and the view is shown correctly.

When I do the same thing on my computer the constraints are not applied. We have compared the settings and view options but we can't see any differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called "live autoresizing" and its failure may be a bug. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814840/storyboard-how-do-i-let-xcode-automatically-update-frames-when-i-change-layout) where other people had a similar problem. In fact, just now it was working for me, but when I turned it off and on again in the Editor menu, it no longer did, even after restarting.

Setting up a keyboard shortcut for Update Frames in the Xcode preferences -> key bindings could help speed things up a lot. In my case I found it listed twice and one of them had a shortcut already assigned, but it didn't work. Ah, Xcode.

You can go to [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com) and file a radar, but if you're going to do that see [this page](http://fixradarorgtfo.com) first.

Comment: Like the question you refered to one solution is to make sure that “Descendants” in the “Resizing Behavior” popup menu is enabled. It wasn't enabled for me, that solved it for me.

Comment: Apparently Xcode 8.3 which I have been using has removed this button for some reason so I couldn't check it. Anyway if my link solved your issue you can mark it as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if use autolayout and use size classes is enabled in the file inpector in the .xib file.